# Sequence forming a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

> The sequences $(x_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ in $\mathbb R$ , all or almost all $\neq 0$ with operations defined component by component, form a vector space V over $\mathbb R$.
>
> Find a basis of V, i.e. a subset $B \subset V $, in which a finite number of elements is linearly independent and which spans $B$ in a way, that every element of $V$ can be created as a linear combination of elements in $B$.

Does anyone have an idea? A hint would be enough since I actually want to do it on my own, but I am missing an approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should say that almost all are zero. Then, consider the sequences where all are zero except at one place you have a $1$. Show that everybody is a linear combination of these and then that these are linearly independent.

Comment: Well, almost all $=0$ is permitted by the description of the task

Comment: You wrote almost all $\not=0$. This should be almost all $=0$.